# Run old version FindBugs with new version of Gradle and JDK

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project that needs to use an older version of Findbugs but I would like to use the version of Gradle that I currently have installed on my computer and that is on my Path.

Here is part of my configuration with Java version and Findbugs:

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
findbugs {
    effort = "max"
    ignoreFailures = false
    // Only run findbugs on source files
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
    // File has exclusions for Findbugs
    excludeFilter = file("${rootProject.projectDir}/config/findbugs.xml")
    toolVersion = '2.0.3'
}
```

The target project needs to be compiled for Java 7 with a Java 7 compatible version of FindBugs. Here is the version of Gradle and Java that are on the Path:

```
$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-09-08 10:40:39 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     e6cf70745ac11fa943e19294d19a2c527a669a53

Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0 (Oracle Corporation 25.0-b70)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

And if I try and run the FindBugs task I get the following error output:

```
$ gradle  :findbugsMain
:Project:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:Project:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:Project:classes UP-TO-DATE
:Project:findbugsMain FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Project:findbugsMain'.
> The version of FindBugs (2.0.3) inferred from FindBugs classpath is too low to work with currently used Java version (1.8). Please use higher version of
FindBugs. Inspected FindBugs classpath: [findbugs-2.0.3.jar, jcip-annotations-1.0.jar, jsr305-2.0.1.jar, bcel-2.0.1.jar, jFormatString-2.0.1.jar, dom4j-1.6
.1.jar, asm-3.3.jar, asm-commons-3.3.jar, commons-lang-2.6.jar, AppleJavaExtensions-1.4.jar, jaxen-1.1.6.jar, xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, asm-tree-3.3.jar]
```

How do I configure this project to run an older version of FindBugs appropriately without having to edit my environment variables? How do I get it to run FindBugs with a different JDK than Gradle is currently running with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't configure the JDK used specifically for the Findbugs task, but you can configure gradle to use a specific jvm in general by setting a property in your gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.java.home
```

Not that this java will be used for the whole gradle process and not just for Findbugs, but it does not require to change your environment variables.

Comment: Maybe there is some combination of this property (or another) and the [Wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper.html) task that could be used?

Comment: the wrapper task itself does nothing but generating a bash/batch script plus creating a small jar file. but you could tweak the generated scripts to point to the desired java installation. Anyway. I would prefere to use JAVA_HOME to point to a java7. Is there a reason why you use java8 for creating java7 compliant java code?

Comment: Java 8 is the default for what I am running my local applications for (like  IntelliJ) as well as what I want to be what is used for almost every other project. For this particular project it needs to be Java 7 compliant, and that is why I am looking for a solution for to make a project specific runtime where Gradle is bootstrapped with a specific version of Java or that it runs the FindBugs tasks with a specific version of Java.